# Рисование изображений в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Есть ли в Qt widget или QML - виджет на котором можно рисовать и в дальнейшим производить манипуляции над изображением (ну это уже я буду реализовывать).

Необходимо иметь возможность создавать несколько слоев и рисовать на определенном слое.

QPainter - думаю точно не подойдет он слишком прост для этого, есть ли еще какие средства для этого? или придется все самому реализовать? если это так то что мне пригодится для этого?

Делаю "рисовалку" но усложненную.

Comment: Чем QPainter не угодил?

Comment: `QPainter` это низкоуровневое рисование, в принципе с его помощью можно реализовать все, что угодно, в частности и рисование на отдельных слоях.

Comment: @BeardedBeaver  а есть пример "многослойного" рисования с помощью QPainter?

Comment: Примера нет, но подход на словах следующий - создаем список пиксмапов, заливаем их все прозрачным, один назначаем "текущим", рисуем на текущем, в `paintEvent` виджета в нужном порядке рисуем все пиксмапы-слои один за другим

Comment: я бы советовал для такого плана задачи использовать QGraphicsScene. Он собственно даже реализует минимальный функционал рисовалки. Для реализации слоев придется немного доработать, но сложного в этом не вижу. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-graphicsview.html ( http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-diagramscene-example.html )